# How may I sort strings with more than one pre-requirement?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, list

I have bunch of strings (around ~300) and they are all 4 letter such as
`XYZA, ZHF3, RTt2 etc.` I want to sort them depending on the 2 requirement.

1. Sort them in order of last 2 letters
2. Sort the words that includes same 2 last letters depending on first 2 letter

Which means I have strings in format XXYY and want to sort them with the rules shown.

I'm trying to do it with `sort -k.1.3,1.4` but the ones with same are sorted randomly such as `15AA, a2AA, 0CAA etc.` How may I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-k` can be used more than once. When there are multiple key fields, later keys are compared only after all earlier keys compare equal.

```
<datafile sort -k 1.3,1.4 -k 1.1,1.2
```

And remember sorting depends on `LC_COLLATE`.

Comment: I were affected by LC_COLLATE. LC_COLLATE=C solved the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Perform the operations in reverse – first sort by the *first two* letters, and then by the last two. I think you can even do this:

```
cat file | sort | sort -k 1.3 -s
```

The `sort` command can perform a *stable* sort, i.e. if two lines are "equal" it will preserve their relative order to each other. So in the second step, the lines with identical 3rd-4th letters will conveniently retain their order from the first step.

Comment: I think you're affected by LC_COLLATE – that is, you're assuming the `sort` command will always use ASCIIbetical order, but in reality it uses *locale-defined* order which is usually `AaBbCc..Gg..Qq..Zz` in locales using Unicode collation. (So the order *is* correct, just under different rules.) Export `LC_COLLATE=C` if you want the program to use ASCII (i.e. byte) order.

Comment: Ditto. Or use `LC_COLLATE=C sort …`.

Comment: I were affected by LC_COLLATE. LC_COLLATE=C solved the issue. Thank you :)